# What model are these forks?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, fork, vintage, campagnolo

Recently, I picked up this set of threaded forks. I saw the chrome and it looked clean enough so took a better look and saw the make ‘campagnolo’ written on the stem.

In the end I got them for the grand total of £3 so I was happy.

Does anyone know the model of these forks?

[image]

Comment: What do you need this information for? Especially the year looks unneeded. Do you have some particular problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I wanted to know the worth of them because there’s no point putting really expensive forks on a rubbish bike for example because they will probably get scratched. The year isn’t that important but I like to use parts from the same sort of age as the bike because that’s just how I am. No particular problem, just wanted to know more about them

Comment: The steerer tube was really long. Too long for most of my bikes so I carefully cut it down to fit so that it fits on my Peugeot 103 carbolite. The forks can actually fit 700c wheels and the front brake works as it should. They feel decent to ride with and definitely have made the bike lighter

Answer (score 2):

Right now you have a "worth" of 3 pounds, because it was "worth" it to the seller to have 3 pounds, and you thought the forks were worth parting wiht 3 pounds for.

If you weren't there, the worth would be 0, and if multiple buyers were there, the price would rise until only one was left. That might be 4 pounds or 400.

**Worth** or value is what someone is prepared to pay for an item.

---

They're nice-looking forks and provided there are no cracks, dents, or damage I'd totally ride them.  You'll need a bike with a matching headtube and cups that fit the headset.

Also, its hard to get the scale from the photo but either the steerer tube is really long, or the fork tines are short.  It could be for a 20" or 24" wheel - I suggest you fit your expected front wheel and then see if the brakes reach, before disassembling any headsets.  
 Brakes are super-critical, and front brakes even more-so.  Don't be tempted to go without front brakes if they don't fit.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably never know who made the forks or what tubing was used. You have some headset parts but not a complete set. if the dropouts are stamped, it's a hint at the quality. They look good, hopefully you'll get some good use.

it isn't worth a fortune, so you got a good deal, maybe you can double your money.